# How to calculating column from multi choice column?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a multi choice column with data in it, that I'd to use a Managed Column to gather the data from.

Modules = Multi Choice Column

Modules_Index = Managed Content Type Column Capture Modules Column as a Single Line of Text

Is there a way to run a workflow or java script to update the Modules_Index columns?

I don't believe the Multi Choice Column is supported by the calculate value field, so the following didn't work:
=[Module]  or =Text[Module]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me: 
Reference: https://sharepointhacker.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/choice-field-multiple-select-multiple-columns-part-1/

This is a hack. SharePoint doesn't technically allow this. To trick SharePoint

1. Create your choice field with your name, Modules.
2. Do not select choice, instead select single line of text.
3. Once created, create your calculated column and set it =[Modules]
4. Delete Modules
5. Create Modules, and select it as multi choice column.

Now your calculated column will equal that multi choice column. Keep in mind that you can't edit the Calculate Column. it will error because it is not suppose to read the choice field.